# lsblk doesnt match df -h

Tags: 16.04

I recently added some disk space, I can see it in `lsblk`

```
sdb              8:16   0  63.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1           8:17   0  63.5G  0 part /var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodata
```

but not in `df -h`

```
/dev/sdb1                        49G   33G   17G  67% /fastdisk
```

I'm also not sure why the paths are different between the two tools. I have restarted the machine already.

`findmnt`

```
├─/var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodata/_data                                                                /dev/sdb1                      xfs         rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
├.
├.removed for brevity
├.
├─/fastdisk                                                                                              /dev/sdb1                      xfs         rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota
```

Comment: You have one of those directories bind mounted on the other, probably. What does `findmnt` report?

Comment: added output of findmnt

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this is an xfs file system so I needed to use:

`sudo xfs_growfs /fastdisk/`